# Are properties in JavaScript internally objects as well?

Tags: javascript, properties, ecmascript-5

For a long time, I've been working with JavaScript and have a good understanding of the idea of objects and properties.

But I never thought of one thing, until recently, that because all properties in JavaScript have internal attributes such as `[[Configurable]]`, isn't it the case that **internally, all properties are objects themselves**?

I looked at the ECMAScript spec, but there seems to be no *explicit mention of this idea*.

Comment: This would be an implementation detail. It's entirely possible that the parent object has a list of configuration for each property which is separate.

Comment: I don't really see how this would affect any JS code you write, though.

Comment: [this part](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.6) of the spec may be what you're after that talks about _named data properties_ and _named accessor properties_ (both maintaining a set of boolean values - that being attributes such as [[Configurable]] etc.)

Comment: Sometimes, somethings are purely for the purposes of better visualising and understanding something, not to help in writing better code.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ you can think of them as objects, if you wish.

Comment: An important distinction is: "are they objects according to the spec" or "are they implemented as objects at some level in the runtime"? Because for the second one I guess the answer is usually yes for most implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification [states](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.6):

> A named data property associates a name with an ECMAScript language value and a set of Boolean attributes.

... which does not use the PropertyDescriptor:

> The Property Descriptor type is used to explain the manipulation and reification of named property attributes. Values of the Property Descriptor type are records composed of named fields where each field’s name is an attribute name and its value is a corresponding attribute value as specified in 8.6.1. In addition, any field may be present or absent.

So while PropertyDescriptors are *records*, properties of an object are not. The engine must have some mechanism to store the attributes and values of an object. How it does that is implementation specific. Storing a record of value and attributes in a list would be a possible implementation.

---

In reality, engines use the concept of *hidden classes*, that is they create a structure containing metadata such as the property names and their descriptors for all objects with the same shape, and the structures representing objects only store a reference to the hidden class and the values the object holds. As such properties are not really stored as "objects".

[This blog](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties) shows how hidden classes work in V8, one of the well known implementations.

Comment: Yeah, even I just read the article on the V8 blog. Now I feel that properties aren't actually objects. When we access a property the engine resolves a reference to some object that contains all the information related to the property's name. The property itself isn't an object, rather it merely is a mechanism to obtain that object from memory that contains all the information related to the property.

Comment: So when I do `obj.x`, `x` isn't an object stored in memory with fields on it. Rather, it's the case (at least in V8) that the property's name (which is often a string) is used to obtain the corresponding entry in some internal list that contains the value of the property and maybe points to some other location where the attributes such as `[[Configurable]]` are actually defined.

Answer (score -2):

As defined in Mozilla docs: A property in JavaScript consists of either a string-valued name or a Symbol and a property descriptor.

So, to answer your question a property can be made up of a symbol (a primitive) and property descriptor (an object).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Comment: Symbols aren't objects, they are primitives.

Comment: Symbol is a a built-in object as you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: Read the rest of the sentence: "Symbol is a built-in object whose constructor **returns a symbol primitive**" (emphasis mine). The symbols used for properties are not the Symbol constructor, they are symbol values.